# Single image as launch image for iOS 6 and iOS 7 in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uilaunchimagefile, launchimage

For iPhone app which support iOS 6 and iOS 7, we can use single image as launch image for both  os versions. But in iPad, iOS 6 version launch image size should be 1024x748 and iOS 7 version launch image size should be 1024x768. Due to separate images, i feel the app size get increased unnecessary. Is there any way to reduce the app size or any way to use a single image for both version of the app?

Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not be best answer to your query (there may be better solution), in iOS7 as application gets full access of screen, splash image size is 1024x768, where in iOS6 access starts after status bar so it's 1024x748.

If you will check option [Hide status bar during application launch] than for iOS 6 splash size will be 1024x768, so you don't need to add any extra image, check attached image to see that option in Target->general settings

[image]